# How to print out a nested array effectively in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a nested array:

```
[1, 2, [3, 4, [5, [6]], 7], 8, 9]
```

How could I print it in an elegant way to look like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: What is your not elegant way?

Comment: "print" as in `console.log` or "print" like output in html?

Comment: `JSON.parse("[" + [1,2,[3,4,[5,[6]],7],8,9].join(",") + "]")`

Comment: This is called "flattening". Google for that.

Comment: Also take a look at Underscore's `_.flatten`.

Answer (score 2):

```
function printArray(arr) {
    if ( typeof(arr) == "object") {
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            printArray(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    else console.log(arr);
}

printArray([1,2,[3,4,[5,[6]],7],8,9]);
```

Comment: I would just change `document.write` to `console.log`. It's very bad practice to use `document.write`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, it will flatten your array.

```
let a = [1, 2, [3, 4, [5, [6]], 7], 8, 9];
const flatten = arr => arr.reduce((a, b) => a.concat(Array.isArray(b) ? flatten(b) : b), []);
console.log(flatten(a));
```

Actually, you can find it here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

## Update 1:

Here is another solution.

```
function flatten(arr) {
    var x;
    x = JSON.stringify(arr);
    x = "[" + x.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "") + "]";
    return JSON.parse(x);
}
console.log(flatten(a));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way of doing it with ES6:

```
var nested = [1, 2, [3, 4, [5, [6]], 7], 8, 9];

var flat = [].concat(nested);

for(var i = 0; i < flat.length; i++) {
    if(Array.isArray(flat[i])) {
        flat.splice(i, 1, ...flat[i--]);  
    }
}

console.log(flat);
```

Comment: The result is : [1, 2, 3, 4, Array[2], 7, 8, 9] in chrome or [1, 2, 3, 4, [5, [6]], 7, 8, 9] in firefox.

Comment: yeah saw it, updated the answer with a working solution @Y.C.

Answer (score 0):

@Yaser solution seems very elegant. Just in case you want to use a functional framework, here an example using **ramda**

```
const arr = R.flatten([1, 2, [3, 4, [5, [6]], 7], 8, 9]);
console.log(arr); //[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

When using **node.js**, the following gives me almost what you requested, except that the printed output has no spaces after the commas:

```
console.log('[%s]', [1, 2, [3, 4, [5, [6]], 7], 8, 9]);
```

Calling `toString()` on the array may be necessary to get the same results in other environments:

```
console.log('[%s]', [1, 2, [3, 4, [5, [6]], 7], 8, 9].toString());
```

Comment: For me this displays `[Array[5]]` in the console.

Comment: See my updated answer.